# Dynamic table creation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have an application where users can create their own Mysql database tables using a limited front-end interface. The front-end handles security, name duplication, etc.

I've read a lot of similar SO answers, but most of them end up having solutions like "Don't create dynamic tables, just create a few tables and foreign keys to relate them together". This isn't really an option though, because each user is really making their own tables, which are independent of another user's tables. A user can have multiple tables associated with themselves.

So here's my question: If I have lots of tables (say a couple million), would it better to stick all the tables in one database, or create a database for each user, and then stick the user's tables in that database, in terms of performance and maintenance? I talked to a friend about this, and he mentioned it being easier to replicate and scale lots of databases than lots of tables.

Also, a side question: Do any existing ORM's have the ability to do something like this - creating dynamic databases/tables? I'm using straight up SQL at the moment, but it'd be nice to have an already built/tested library instead, but I understand I have kind of an usual problem type.

Comment: I can say this about -> *"or create a database for each user"* - Very bad idea. Think of the maintenance, etc.

Comment: you'll end up with horrible performance. mysql query caches are keyed to tables. If you have a million tables, and even a small fraction of them are "active", you'll be trashing your cache constantly.

Comment: Marc B, So would it be better to instead have a million databases with one or two tables each? Would that still mess up the caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using myisam storage engine, you have to look also into the performance of the underlying engine.

Without testing, I would favour um directory for db. It is 1 million entries (say) of directories vs 2 million table entries to be searched. This is assuming MySQL merely uses the API of the file szstem to access the dbs/tables.

With myisam, the limit on the number of tables/dbs depends only on the file system.

From a logical point of view (think easier application maintenance) and namespace management, I also would favour 1 dir per user.